# imageview works only in Android Studio preview, but not on device or emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, imageview

I've a problem with an image in an activity.
For some reason the ImageView is visible in the Android Studio preview, but not when I build it on device or emulator. In any other activity it's working correctly. I'm not an expert in Android and I can't figure out what is the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MapsActivity"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/ColoreSfondo">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numeroRisultatiMappa"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/numeroRisultatiMappa"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logoDescription"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonMapToHome"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numeroRisultatiMappa"
        tools:context="MapsActivity" />
        

    <Button
        android:text="@string/buttonhome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMapToHome"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/toList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMapToList"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonMapToHome"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonMapToHome"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/numeroRisultatiMappa"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonMapToHome"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonMapToHome" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is wrong post with images please

Comment: in place of app:srcCompact try android:src

Comment: Is there any error that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your fragment tag with below code.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonMapToHome"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        tools:context="MapsActivity"/>
```

And also in imageview please change `app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"` to `android:src="@drawable/app_logo"`

Comment: What's wrong with srcCompat? Assuming an AppCompatActivity is used

Comment: Changing the fragment block, throws "circular dependencies" exception... but changing app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" to android:src="@drawable/app_logo" actually solved the problem... I don't understand why but it does... thanks!

Comment: To remove the circular dependency you have to remove android:layout_above="@+id/map" from ImageView